# Youtube Upload Video with accented (è,à,ò,ì and so on) letters in title/desc/tags

Tags: zend-framework, youtube-api

Dear,
I'm using Zend Api for uploading videos on Youtube and have some problems with accented letters... Is there a correct method to andle them?
thanks.

Comment: The accented letters are perfectly legal on Youtube: see for example this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnpqg5HPNms (the word caffè is in title and tag) and the youtube admininistration tool admit them. I need to know how to use them via Zend. thanks

Comment: those are likely unicode characters, no? Can you not capture the characters and send them to the Youtube API?

Answer (score 0):

remove them before upload :)

[this is example](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Sluggable/Util/Urlizer.php)

Comment: The accented letters are perfectly legal on Youtube: see for example this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnpqg5HPNms (the word caffè is in title and tag) and the youtube admininistration tool admit them. I need to know how to use them via Zend. thanks